# memory limit in php

Tags: php, curl

I'm making a curl request , witch was working perfectly for weeks, and now it's returning this error:

> Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 76889 bytes)

The weird part is that i've checked php.ini and phpinfo and both tell me memory limit is

> memory_limit   1028M

I've also tried

```
ini_set("memory_limit","400M");
```

In the top of the file to make sure, but still, getting this error.

This is happening in both development and production servers.

Comment: Can't you make memory_limit to unlimited and try ? make sure curl request to the same domain.

Comment: Are you making a curl request to another domain?

Comment: Check that you're using the correct php.ini, CLI often has a different php.ini than web

Comment: @DaveRandom This is 256KB, not MB

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt Oh yeh, I thought that looked wrong but my sanity filter ignored it for some reason.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using

Comment: Yes, its to another domain. it's a call to an api.  
when calling ini_get("memory_limit") on the page, correct memory limit is shown  
php version is 5.2.6

Comment: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/php-memory-limit-problem-69715.html - TL;DR it's being caused by suhosin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DaveRandom nailed it. suhosin (I wasn't even aware we had that
>   installed) was causing de issue by "overprotecting" the server.
>
> [forums.cpanel.net/f5/php-memory-limit-problem-69715.html][1] - TL;DR
>   it's being caused by suhosin. – DaveRandom
>
> Thanks to all!
>
> [1]: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/php-memory-limit-problem-69715.html

UPS, that somehow fiexd the error in that part, but another part of the webapp is throwing same error.

I have no clue where to look at.
it says memory limit is 1028M in php info, if i change it via ini_set, new value appears using ini_get, and now I have set suhosin to simulation. that somehow fixed the first problem, but now it reappeared.